# How to control the display of numeric or alpha numeric keyboard on device?

Tags: mobile, keyboard, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I want to restrict type of entry (numeric or alphanumeric) by displaying the appropriate keyboard.

How to acheive that using JDEVELOPER MAF 12C?

Answer (score 0):

i still dont get why people nowadays cant use google .... this took about 30 seconds to find, and i have never even heard of MAF before :

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile200/mobile/tag-ref/toc.htm#amx:inputText

```
<amx:inputText inputType="number">
```

> inputType
>
> Sets the type of data that the user should be allowed to provide. If
>   secret has been set to true or if the rows attribute has been set to
>   larger than 1, the input type will be treated as "text". This will not
>   guarantee an input format nor prevent the user from entering other
>   types of characters, it only serves as a mechanism to request that the
>   mobile device present the user with an optimized input mechanism for a
>   particular type of input value (e.g. a virtual keyboard with numbers
>   primarily displayed). Valid values are number, email, url, tel, or
>   text (default).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should have got it too

Comment: You should have got "what"?